# how to redefine the sorting algorithm of std::set?

Tags: c++, set

For example,

```
#include <set>
class myclass
{
public:
    int a;
};
int main()
{
    std::set<myclass*> arr;
    for(m=0;m<3; m++){
        myclass * p = new myclass;
        p->a=m;
        arr.insert(p);
    }
}
```

In the above code, `arr` is sorting the address rather than the value `a`. How to make `arr`'s member rank according the value of `a`.

Comment: Why are you storing pointers in the `set` in the first place?  This is normally not what you want to do.

Comment: provide second template argument to set: `std::set<myclass, MyCustomComparer>`

Comment: what is `public a;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Probably the pointers are to fix the compiler error when trying to use `myclass` directly, because `myclass` isn't (yet) comparable.

Comment: If you stored `std::set<myclass>` instead of pointers, observed the compiler errors, then you would get an error that may have been more helpful to you.  Basically, it looks like you fell right into the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) trap.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Maybe, but it could also be the inexplicable love that newbies have for pointers.